# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.verifyProperties

Tags: hibernate

While trying to build the session factory I get this. Very little turns up in an Internet search. But it's got me dead-in-the-water for days now. Thanks.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.verifyProperties(Ljava/util/Map;)V
at   org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder.buildServiceRegistry(ServiceRegistryBuilder.java:244)
```

Using hibernate version:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.1.Final</version>
  <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

---

```
public class HibernateUtils {

private static final String DATABASE_HOST = "host_to_db";

private static SessionFactory factory;
private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

public static void init() {
Configuration config = getConfiguration();
config.configure();

serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
config.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();

config.setSessionFactoryObserver(new SessionFactoryObserver() {

@Override
public void sessionFactoryCreated(SessionFactory factory) { }

@Override
public void sessionFactoryClosed(SessionFactory factory) {
ServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(serviceRegistry);
}
});

factory = config.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
}
```

Comment: when you do maven install do you get all the hibernate jars?

Comment: They are:  (BTW - I get the same error if I just use hibernate-core without c3p0)

hibernate-c3p0-4.1.1.Final.jar

c3p0-0.9.1.jar (via hibernate-c3p0)

hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar  (via hibernate-core)

hibernate-core-4.1.1.Final.jar  (via hibernate-c3p0)

hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar  (via hibernate-core)

javassist-3.15.0-GA.jar  (via hibernate-c3p0)

jboss-logging-3.1.0.GA.jar  (via hibernate-c3p0)

jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar  (via hibernate-c3p0)

xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar  (via hibernate-c3p0)

Answer (score 6):

You have a conflict with hibernate-core.jar versions, the Map version was added only in later versions (around 4.2.X  maybe?), check your Eclipse/Maven 'Dependency Hierarchy' tab to analyze version conflicts.

```
public static void verifyProperties(Map<?,?> configurationValues)
```

My problem was resolved only when I deleted my local Hibernate Maven repo and ran install again.