# error in creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory'

Tags: java, hibernate

I created a JSF + Spring + Hibernate + JPA Project, when I try to build the project I'm getting this error :

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in URL
>   [file:/home/aimad/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/jsf-primefaces/WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.verifyProperties(Ljava/util/Map;)

which is caused by :

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.verifyProperties(Ljava/util/Map;)V

I already read the answer on this post : [java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.verifyProperties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11553202/4991526)

and it says that :

> the Map version was added only in later versions (around 4.2.X
>   maybe?)

and as you can see I have the latest version, and the solution which was provided was :

> I deleted my local Hibernate Maven repo and ran install again

which I tried and didn't work

this is my pom.xml :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.tybasoft.tuto</groupId>
    <artifactId>Primefaces-JPA-Spring-Primefaces-Sample</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Primefaces-JPA-Spring-Primefaces-Sample Maven Webapp</name>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>prime-repo</id>
            <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Faces Implementation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Faces Library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Primefaces Version 5 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>5.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JSP Library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JSTL Library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Primefaces Theme Library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
            <artifactId>blitzer</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JPA -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring MVC framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- MySQL Connector -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.38</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hibernate JPA -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0.ga</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

## Application context :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">


    <bean id="etudiantDao"
        class="com.tybasoft.tuto.dao.EtudiantDaoImpl">
    </bean>

    <bean id="etudiantService"
        class="com.tybasoft.tuto.service.EtudiantServiceImpl">
        <property name="etudiantDao" ref="etudiantDao"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tybasoft" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="toor" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="persistenceUntiManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath*:persistence.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultDataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitManager" ref="persistenceUntiManager"></property>
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="jsf-primefaces"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"></property>
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
</beans>
```

## persistence.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="jsf-primefaces" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
         <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
         <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
      </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Answer (score 1):

@Yukina Spoonatte, you could try this way.

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
<property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath*:persistence.xml" />
<property name="persistenceUnitName" value="jsf-primefaces" />
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
<property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
<property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
</bean>
 
<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter"
class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
<property name="database" value="HSQL" />
<property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect" />
</bean>
 
<bean id="jpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
```