# NoSuchMethodError - org.hibernate.cfg.Environment

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, servlets

I have a problem with hibernate. Issue: *Error creating bean with name 'emf' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.verifyProperties(Ljava/util/Map;)V*

It's xml file (servlet-context):http://pastebin.com/BRYvbVTg

And, I have only one dependency from hibernate:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

In classpath, tried add all packages, have the same effect

Full stack trace:http://pastebin.com/wJy7QfPW

Comment: Better to add a full stack trace.

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553202/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-hibernate-cfg-environment-verifyproperties, looks like some older version of hibernate on the classpath

Comment: How I can delete local libs from Maven (Linux)?

Answer (score 1):

1. As @v.ladynev mentioned, provide  full stack trace.
2. To delete a local lib, locate and navigate to your .m2 folder, /repository/org and delete the hibernate folder
3. Consider defining your entityManagerFactory as

```
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />       
<property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
</property>
<property name="jpaProperties">
    <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>         
        <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
    </props>
</property>
<property name="packagesToScan" value="ru.mrchebik.model"/>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: It's not resolve my problem.